# If $H,K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, is it true that $H \cap K \leq H$ and $H \cap K \leq K$?

Tags: group-theory

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm doing introductory group theory and every text I've encountered mentions only that if $H \leq G$ and $K \leq G$, then $H \cap K \leq G$.

However, is it true that $H \cap K \leq H$ and $H \cap K \leq K$? It seems pretty clear to me, since $H \cap K$ is a group and is a subset of both $K$ and $H$, so it should be true. I just can't tell if I'm missing something obvious or if this is just trivial...

Comment: Yes, that's true precisely for the reason that you said.

Comment: Reading it as a simple set intersection, it's obviously true, and reading it as "the group generated by the elements $H\cap K$", which we might suppose is larger, it's still true, since elements of $H$ can't generate a larger group than $H$ and the same applies for $K$. The more interesting outcome is that those elements must actually themselves form a group - the group generated by the elements of $H\cap K$ contains only those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A subgroup of $G$ is just a subset $H$ such that the restriction of the group operation of $G$ to $H$ gives a group.

So you are fine since the group operation on $H\cap K$ is the restriction of that on $H$ (or on $K$) since these are just that from $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Without loss of generality, I will prove $H\cap K\le H$. I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Since $H,K\le G$, we have $e\in H$ and $e\in K$. Hence $e\in H\cap K\neq\varnothing$.

By definition $H\cap K=\{\ell\in G\mid \ell\in H\land\ell\in K\}$. Thus $H\cap K\subseteq H$.

Let $a, b\in H\cap K$. Then $a,b\in H$, so $ab^{-1}\in H$ as $H\le G$; similarly, $ab^{-1}\in K$. But then $ab^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

Hence $H\cap K\le H$.